# Find the streamlines of the velocity field

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I have to find the streamlines of the following velocity fields:

1. $$u=x(1+2t), v=y$$
2. $$u=xy, v=0$$

I have done the following:

1. $$\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dy}{v} \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{x(1+2t)}=\frac{dy}{y} \Rightarrow \frac{\ln x}{1+2t}=\ln y+c \Rightarrow y=Ce^{\frac{\ln x}{1+2t}} \Rightarrow y=Cx^{\frac{1}{1+2t}}$$

   Is this correct??
2. $$\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dy}{v} \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{xy}=\frac{dy}{0}$$

   How could we continue??

Comment: If you've divided by $0$ you haven't taken the limits properly. (By your derivation still non-existent)

Comment: What do you mean?? That I should write only $$\frac{dx}{u}$$ ?? @Zach466920

Comment: No, only that you'll have to keep the v as a limit approaching 0 until the end of the problem.

Comment: And how can we solve it?? How can we find the streamlines?? @Zach466920

Comment: You'd have to solve a differential equation for the velocity potential, then find the values where it's equal to an arbitrary constant. However, these two problems shown don't really fit into my typical mold, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Do yo mean the following?? $$\frac{dx}{u}=c$$ @Zach466920

Comment: Streamlines are **instantaneously tangential to the velocity vector of the flow**. I hope you can see that in the second case (since v = 0) we therefore have horizontal streamlines except when $x=0$ or $y=0$ where $u=0$ (the flow here is stationary). You can check the first answer by computing $\frac{dy}{dt}$ from your expression for $y(t)$ and then $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$.